# UWP: How do I remove a Binding in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How do I remove a Binding in code? In one case I used SetBinding to create a Binding. In another case I created a Binding via XAML. But there don't seem to be a way to completely remove the Binding.

Comment: Can you just clobber the value with `Foo.Bar = value`?

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways you can go about it.

Let's assume that you have the below XAML

```
<Page>
  ...
  <Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MyPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
  </Page.DataContext>
  ...
  <Grid x:Name="rootLayout">
    <ListView x:name="PeopleListView" ItemSource="{Binding myItemsCollection}"/>
    <Textbox x:name="SomeTextBox" Text="{Binding myTextProp}"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Now in C# there are a bunch of ways you can remove the binding of the `PeopleListView` control. Below are a few.

1. Set the `DataContext` of the `PeopleListView` to null. This would make it not use parent `DataContext`.
2. Another way is to set the `PeopleListView.ItemSource` property to null. This would remove the existing `XAML` binding and replace it with null.

Comment: Sorry but BindingOperations.ClearBinding() is not available in UWP. It appears to be a WPF-only feature. Everything else made sense, though.

Comment: @LeBrownJones It's mentioned in the docs. (I've shared the link) that's the reason it's a part of the answer. I generally use the `DataContext` much more easy to maintain and quick to modify. I recommend you use the `DataContext`

Comment: If you look at the top of the page that you linked me to, it shows that you are in the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) section.

Comment: @LeBrownJones I am sorry for that. I missed that part out. I've  updated my answer for the same. If my answer does solve your query please do mark it as an answer

Comment: You need to use ClearValue on the dependency object itself.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to a note in the [Remarks section of the UWP Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingoperations.setbinding?view=winrt-22621#remarks) on SetBinding:

> Calling the `SetBinding` method and passing in a new Binding object won't necessarily remove an existing binding. Instead, you should first call the `DependencyObject.ClearValue` method, then call `SetBinding`.

So I'm guessing you'll have to call [ClearValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.clearvalue?view=winrt-22621) on the target dependency property to clear all the existing bindings.

Hopefully you only have one binding set up so you won't have to reinstate any other bindings you still need  .